# Get tile notifications count Windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone

Is there a way to get the current count of `Tile notifications` on `Windows Phone` and update it locally. I need to update the `tile` count locally if I have read a notification via `push notification` / `toast` without hitting the push service from the server end.

Say for eg. I have the `tile count` 6. As soon as I receive a push notification and I click on it, I want the `tile count` to be reduced by 1. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot read out information from a `ShellTile`. You can only update them.

What you could do is saving the information of the counter or anything else on your server that pushes. It can preperate the notification as you wish. I guess this is not the way you want to deal with it but it is the only way.

Comment: Yes I ended up updating the `ShellTile` count to 0 on the app launch.